# Drop Down Nav Menu (using Parent and Children Pages) in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have four Parent Pages and six Children Pages tied to each Parent Page in Wordpress CMS. Is there a plugin or php and Wordpress code that will allow me to create a drop down menu so that the Children pages are the links in the drop down menu?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/ you can use this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

http://goudendouche.com/plugins/dropdown-menu-plugin/